# Using hibernate validator JodaTime bean validation constraints in JBoss

Tags: jboss7.x, jodatime, hibernate-validator

We have an enterprise application that uses the Joda DateTime library. The application is deployed into a JBoss 7.2.0 Alpha1 Container. Some classes in our domain model have @Past annotations on fields of type DateTime. In order to validate these constraints we'd like to use the constraint validators provided by hibernate-validator. Therefore we added a dependency 'org.hibernate.validator' to the MANIFEST.MF of our ear file. We are using version 2.0 of the Joda library. Therefore we have packaged the joda-time-2.0.jar file in our ear. We are not using the version 1.6.2 that is available as a module of JBoss 7

When validating an object with a DateTime field following exception is thrown:

```
10:51:41,140 ERROR [org.acme.GlobalExceptionHandler] (EJB default - 10) Exception caught by global exception handler: javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: No validator could be found for type: org.joda.time.DateTime
at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ConstraintTree.verifyResolveWasUnique(ConstraintTree.java:383) [hibernate-validator-4.2.0.Final.jar:4.2.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ConstraintTree.findMatchingValidatorClass(ConstraintTree.java:364) [hibernate-validator-4.2.0.Final.jar:4.2.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ConstraintTree.getInitializedValidator(ConstraintTree.java:313) [hibernate-validator-4.2.0.Final.jar:4.2.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:144) [hibernate-validator-4.2.0.Final.jar:4.2.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:117) [hibernate-validator-4.2.0.Final.jar:4.2.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.validator.metadata.MetaConstraint.validateConstraint(MetaConstraint.java:84) [hibernate-validator-4.2.0.Final.jar:4.2.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:452) [hibernate-validator-4.2.0.Final.jar:4.2.0.Final]
```

After some debugging we detected that the call to 'TypeUtils.isAssignable( validatorType, type )' in 'ConstraintTree.findSuitableValidatorTypes' fails since the available validator types are taken from the Joda library that has been shipped with JBoss instead of the Joda library that is packaged in our ear file.

I guess we are doing something wrong regarding classloading. Can anybody give me a hint?

Comment: Using the joda-time-1.6.2 library that comes with JBoss I cannot get it to work either. Can you get it to work with 1.6.2?

Comment: As far as I understood the code the problem is a classloading issue. The available types cached by hibernate-validator have been loaded by the module loader of the 'org.hibernate.time' jboss module whereas the DateTime given as input for validation is from my ear. I.e. it has been loaded by the ear file classloader. Therefore the call to 'Class.isAssignableFrom' will always fail. No matter if it is Joda 2.0 or 1.6.2. Since we use feature of 2.0 we cannot use the Joda module shipped with JBoss.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried adding a *jboss-deployment-structure.xml* to your ear file? This way you should be able to exclude the Joda time module:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.joda.time"/>
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

See also https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Class+Loading+in+AS7

Answer (score 2):

Following Hardy's idea I solved my problem creating a *jboss-deployment-structure.xml* in my application's *WEB-INF* folder containing this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.hibernate.validator" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

In stead of excluding *org.joda.time* I excluded *org.hibernate.validator*. I hope this works for you too.